# How does Anaconda Prompt prepend its location to PATH?

Tags: python, path, anaconda, command-prompt

I'd like to get a deep understanding on the way Anaconda Prompt prepends its location to PATH.

From the Q&A in [difference between command prompt and anaconda prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993175/difference-between-command-prompt-and-anaconda-prompt), I understand that Anaconda Prompt adds/prepends a bunch of locations to PATH whenever it is activated.

From my knowledge, I'm guessing that this has something to do with scripting & Anaconda Prompt using scripts in its files to prepend those locations to PATH.

If this is so,

1. What are the exact names of these scripts and their locations in Anaconda3?

If not,

2. How exactly does Anaconda Prompt do it? (Step-by-step explanation)

Moreover,

3. Where are the prepended locations stored in PATH?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Re: point 3 - Windows OS?

Comment: @Swift yes. Windows 10.